# how to read a particular number from a pdf file

Tags: java

Suppose i want to read  PNR number from a ticket,so every time it will be different in format(like (PNR):XXXXXX,PNR NUMBER-XXXXXX,PNR NO.-XXXXXX) for different tickets, so how to extract that using java code.

Comment: Use regular expression

Answer (score 1):

For Java regex tutorial you can follow this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/syntax.html)

Here as question is unclear

> > What is content of XXXXXX,
> >
> > Length of X

But this regex `(\(PNR\):|PNR NUMBER-|PNR NO.-)[0-9A-Za-z]{6}`. Here I assumed that length of X is 6, it can be alpha numeric and you are able to read pdf in string.

See below output

[image: Output]

Comment: content of  XXXXXXX is combination of numeric and character for e.g  I555JY or 546775GHC ..it will be  a PNR number or  any Reference number.

Comment: Then above regex will work for alphanumeric and I hard coded the length of X to 6. As from your comment let is not fixed so you can use this regex `(\(PNR\):|PNR NUMBER-|PNR NO.-)[0-9A-Za-z]*`